# Gradle only unit-test main module (using Junit:4.11) (gradle multi-module project)

Tags: java, gradle, junit, build.gradle

I'm currently building a project that depends on another that I got from github, but the unit tests only run for the newly created module, any hints on how to get the unit tests to run in the whole project?

When I `gradle test` I get only the tests for the new module and when I `gradle :module2:test`  I get that Junit successfully tested zero tests.

Architecture

```
->new module (called app)
     ->build.gradle (call it 1- )
->github module (called module2)
     ->build.gradle (call it 2- )
     ->settings.gradle
->settings.gradle
```

Build.gradle 1-

```
    plugins {
    id 'rss.java-application-conventions'
    id 'idea'
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '3.2.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories { jcenter() }

dependencies {
    implementation project(':xmlrss')
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.11'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal() // so that external plugins can be resolved in dependencies section
    mavenCentral()
}

version = '0.1.0'

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'rss.app.App'
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'rss.app.MainClass'
    }
}


test {
    dependsOn(':module2:test')
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        exceptionFormat "short"

        // set options for log level DEBUG
        debug {
            events "started", "skipped", "failed"
            exceptionFormat "full"
        }

        // remove standard output/error logging from --info builds
        // by assigning only 'failed' and 'skipped' events
        info.events = ["failed", "skipped"]
    }
}
```

Build.gradle 2-

```
    plugins {
    id 'rss.java-library-conventions'
    id 'idea'
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '3.2.0'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.santuario', name: 'xmlsec', version: '2.0.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.11'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal() // so that external plugins can be resolved in dependencies section
    mavenCentral()
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        exceptionFormat "short"

        // set options for log level DEBUG
        debug {
            events "started", "skipped", "failed"
            exceptionFormat "full"
        }

        // remove standard output/error logging from --info builds
        // by assigning only 'failed' and 'skipped' events
        info.events = ["failed", "skipped"]
    }
}
```

Settings.gradle (for module2):

```
rootProject.name = 'module2'
```

Settings.gradle (in root folder):

```
rootProject.name = 'rss'
include('app', 'module2')
```

Comment: the module you brought over from GitHub might be junit4 - while you gradle is configured for junit 5. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#executing_legacy_tests_with_junit_vintage